# Any progress on relationship indexes for Neo4j?

Tags: indexing, neo4j, relationship

In older versions of Neo4j (2.3 and prior), you could associate legacy indexes with relationship properties, but that does not appear to be the case any more. However, in the API documentation, there is org.neo4j.graphdb.index with an IndexManager parameter. When you look at IndexManager, there is a RelationshipIndex method - which suggests that this is or may soon be available. My use case is I am constructing a product hierarchy with products, product parts, product sub-parts, etc. and it's important IN THE RELATIONSHIP to have a start and end date between each set of components. Does anybody know of a way to do that in 3.x?

Answer (score 0):

[Legacy (or manual) indexing](https://neo4j.com/docs/java-reference/current/#indexing) is still supported in 3.x. In particular, [relationship indexing](https://neo4j.com/docs/java-reference/current/#indexing-relationships) is still supported. Refer to the documentation for more info.